# What is the name for this filming technique?

Tags: film-techniques

Serving as as a transitional technique, sound effects / visual effect from the upcoming movie scene will play before its scene is presented.

For example, in this video clip below, around 0:08, sink hole becomes a turning wheel.

[One Last Dance](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ek0zKPgKmVI)

Second example:

- Two men are having a conversation in a room and when the camera still focuses in this room but sound effect of a steam train starting starts to play; a few seconds later, the camera switches to a train platform.

Answer (score 1):

This is usually referred to as a [J-cut](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/J_cut). It's called this because when viewing the clips in an editing application, the audio of the incoming clip sticks out in front of the video, and makes a shape similar to the letter "J". It's also sometimes referred to as an audio lead or audio advance.

Likewise, there exists an [L-cut](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L_cut) where the audio from a scene lingers after the video has switched to a new scene.